# Steady state and thermal conductivity

Tags: thermodynamics

Setup:
I am running a simulation of two heat sinks connected by some wires. I set the top heat sink to a constant temperature, and the bottom one to a constant heat flux.

Results:
According to the simulation results, changing the thermal conductivity of the wires does not affect the steady-state temperature of the bottom heat sink - it stays the same regardless of the wire conductivity.

This is curious to me. I think that a higher conductivity will allow heat to transfer faster from the top to the bottom heat sink, and that will raise the steady-state temperature of the bottom heat sink.

Do I have my physics right? The only other possibility I can think of is that the thermal conductivity affects how fast the system reaches equilibrium, but not the final temperatures, but I can't formulate this, so I can't be sure.

Please help.

Comment: Usually, when people say "heat sink" they mean an ideal, infinite, constant-temperature source. It is odd that it should be able to change temperature. But if you *do* have a heat sink that can change temperature (I would rename it from heat sink in that case), then the steady state will **always be** when the two sinks are at equal temperature. Faster heat transfer just makes you reach this equal-temperature steady state faster.

Comment: I haven't made myself clear, then. The top one is what you would call a heat sink. Let's call the bottom one a refrigerator (refrigerators can change temperatures, right?) The problem I'm trying to model concerns heat transfer into the refrigerator (via imperfect insulation) on one hand, and heat pumped out on the  other hand. Does my question make sense now?

Comment: Clearly something is going wrong with the simulation. What is the temperature is the constant-flux component? Does it change when you change the temperature of the constant-temperature component? If not, then maybe it’s not connected properly. Try debugging the simplest possible configuration (e.g., one wire, steady state).